# While multithreading, Flask Error sugests using app_context--but that doesn't work

Tags: multithreading, flask, runtime-error

I've created a route to test sending an email. When visiting /book_blast, i get a runtime error. I've messed around with adding app_context() in different ways, but none of them has eliminated the error. If i remove the sending of the emails, it works. If i remove the threaded sending of emails, and send them normally, it works.

```
@books.route("/book_blast")
```

def book_blast():

```
all_free_books = Book.query.all()

# pass in: username, books, token
subscribers = Mail_Subscription.query.filter(Mail_Subscription.daily_promotions == True).all()

# send emails one-by-one based on user preferences
for subscriber in subscribers:
    user = subscriber.user
    email = subscriber.email
    name = 'Subscriber'
    if user:  # if there is a connected user and not just an email subscriber
        name = user.first_name + " " + user.last_name if user.first_name and user.last_name else user.username

    token_url = url_for('books.email_preferences') + "/" + get_unsubscribe_token_for_email_list(email)
    books = [book for book in all_free_books if
             book.stars >= subscriber.rating and book.reviews >= subscriber.reviews and book.genre in subscriber.genres.split(
                 ',')]
    print(f'{name} ({email}) will receive: {books}')

    html = render_template('book_blast.html', name=name, token_url=token_url, books=books)
    msg = Message(f'Free Books {datetime.datetime.now().date()}',
                  sender=current_app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'],
                  recipients=[email])

    msg.body = f'We have {len(books)} for free today. Visit {url_for("books.email_preferences")} to read more.'
    msg.html = html

    # send emails

    """
    app = current_app
    with app.app_context():
    """

    app = current_app
    app.app_context()

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future = executor.submit(mail.send, msg)
        future.result()

return html
```

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest you to create something like send_email.py that looks something like this.

```
 from flask import current_app, render_template
 from flask_mail import Message
 from threading import Thread
 from . import mail


def send_async_mail(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
         mail.send(msg)

def send_email(to, subject, template, **kwargs):
     app = current_app._get_current_object()
     msg = Message(app.config['MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX'] + subject,
     sender=app.config['MAIL_SENDER'], recipients=[to])
     msg.body = render_template(template + '.txt', **kwargs)
     msg.html = render_template(template + '.html', **kwargs)
     thr = Thread(target=send_async_mail, args=[app, msg])
     thr.start()
     return thr
```

After this inside your view just import the send_mail function

```
   send_email(TO, 'TITLE!','template/location')
```

Also i was using flask mail here too... hope it will help you out a bit.

Comment: Thank you,, dariokl. This worked. I thought I had tried this approach before--following an example from Miguel Grinberg--but it hadn't worked. Following your advice, I used  app = current_app._get_current_object() -- which I had never done before. Previously, i was using app=current_app.

Comment: Yeah i found that in one of Miguels book , and yes that line of code wasnt included in his book i dont know why but im glad you have solved it :)